# Get a Wordpress Widget as iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I want to include a widget from my Wordpress website on a different project.

I have full admin access and I'm looking for the Wordpress site to generate a page with just the widget and no extra content so the iframe can grab it with no extra manipulation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an solution by watching a random Youtube video.

I made a custom template, here's a guide:
https://wpastra.com/guides-and-tutorials/wordpress-custom-page-template/#create-a-custom-page-template-manually

My template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: forIframe */ ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<style>
*, a, html {
color: black;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); the_content(); endwhile; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that I just have the content of the post with no header, headline or anything else. I also removed the remaining styling of the main theme. Note that I left the wp_head() function.

Also the css code has the *a* and *html* named specifically to overwrite the css selector priority list (https://dev.to/one-beyond/css-selectors-priority-1cjh)

I set the wordpress site up with **only** the shortcode to the widget and a html block containing a `<style>` tag to style the content of the page just like I want.

```
[calendar type="list"]

<style> p { color: red; font-size: 10px; ... } </style>
```

Now I can implement a simple `<iframe>` and have only the widget displayed (in my case a listing of future events from my wordpress calendar)

Hopes it helps at least one person